# Using Groovy PowerAssert in Java

Tags: java, maven, groovy, assert

I am using Java EE with Maven.
For readability and easy checks, I want to use [Groovy's PowerAssert](http://dontmindthelanguage.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/groovy-1-7-power-assert/) in production code.

Is there a way of doing this in standard Java classes?

I tried adding the 'groovy-all' package as Maven dependency, but the following code fails. What should I import?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  assert (2 + 2 == 5, "Surprise: this assertion failed!");
}
```

Comment: Are you importing the right Assert? Note that Java has it's own assert...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the code fails to compile, but correct me if I'm wrong.  You're not going to be able to use Groovy-only syntax in your Java classes, I'm afraid.  The guts of groovy for this functionality seem interwoven with Groovy compilation, if a quick look is correct, so I don't think it's really hackable for your java code.  For areas of code where you want groovy functionality, perhaps you can embed scripts.

Comment: Or maybe go the extra mile and use [Spock](http://code.google.com/p/spock/) for your testing

Comment: Yes, I meant fails to compile :) Thanks